# IOS touch tracking code

Tags: ios, touch, tracking

I'm making an app for iPhone in Xcode, and It requires a box to follow my finger only on the X axis. I couldn't find any solution online to this, and my coding knowledge isn't that great.

I've been trying to use **touchesBegan** and **touchesMoved**.

Could someone please write me up some code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` on your **ViewController.h** file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@end
```

Then you declare an `UIImageView` on your **ViewController.m**, like so, with a `BOOL` to track if a touch event is occurring inside your `UIImageView`:

```
@interface ViewController () {
    UIImageView *ballImage;
    BOOL touchStarted;
}
```

Then you initialize the `UIImageView` on `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"];
    ballImage =  [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    [ballImage setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y, ballImage.frame.size.width, ballImage.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:ballImage];
}
```

After that you can start doing your modifications to what's best for you using these methods:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touch_point = [touch locationInView:ballImage];

    if ([ballImage pointInside:touch_point withEvent:event])
    {
        touchStarted = YES;

    } else {

        touchStarted = NO;
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([touches count]==1 && touchStarted) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint p0 = [touch previousLocationInView:ballImage];
        CGPoint p1 = [touch locationInView:ballImage];
        CGPoint center = ballImage.center;
        center.x += p1.x - p0.x;
        // if you need to move only on the x axis
        // comment the following line:
        center.y += p1.y - p0.y; 
        ballImage.center = center;
        NSLog(@"moving UIImageView...");
    }

}
```