# How to recognize which imageView was touched?

Tags: ios

I have a problem because I have on one view four imageViews. I add to every tapGestureRecognizer (On storyboard i connected every imageView with tapGestureRecognizer)  and i want to know witch was taped. I try do it with use this method:

```
    - (IBAction)tapToFullSizeImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
        UIView *tmp = [sender view];
        NSLog(@"Tag %d \n", tmp.tag);
    }
```

but it doesn't work. The function show me randomly tag one of four imageViews tags. Where i do mistake? It is at all posible or not?

Someone can check if you have tha same problem? Or maybe it is a bug.

**UPDATE 1:**

Now I understand. So You used 4 gestureRecognizer and it works. Is it absolutely necessary to use a separate gesture recognizer for each imageview? What if I had 9 or 12 or more image on one view?

It is possible that I didin't describe this case strict and clear about what I meant. 
I tried it that I connect all the imageViews (four) of a one tabGestureRecognizer controll in interface builder. CTRL + drag the blue line from the imageview to gesture controll. 4 to 1. (picture)

//Sorry I am new to this site and I can't add pictures.

as I did it with four switches and one function to guide them. (picture)

//Sorry I can't add pictures

Switches are working perfectly but gestures not. Anyone know why? I thought that anyone caught touching gesture will be clearly assigned to the picture from it was called. But it isn't and here is the problem anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: It is possible and it should work. How have you set up the images? Are you sure that you have given them tags correctly?

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097855/ios-tapgesturerecognizer-issues

Comment: Please refer to my answer on how to detect touches on a specific UIImageView. Maybe that will you help you out too. Here is the link for the answer to this question: [IOS touch tracking code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146367/ios-touch-tracking-code/23146507#23146507)

Comment: Thank you for all Comment .
@Smick if your method works also in Scrollview ?
More specifically, a method **locationInView**

`CGPoint tapLocation = [ gesture locationInView : self.galleryView ] ;
    for ( UIImageView * imageview in self.galleryView.subviews ) {
        if ( CGRectContainsPoint ( imageView.frame , tapLocation ) ) {
            [ ImageView removeFromSuperview ] ;
        }
    }`

Comment: I haven't used it in a scroll view, but I think there is no reason why it wouldn't. Test and see :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same as you described:

- 4 UIImageView, with tag 1,2,3,4
- 4 UITapGestureRecognizer
- Each imageView is linked to one of the gestureRecognizer

My log showing:

```
2014-04-18 21:47:27.721 CaseStudy[22400:60b] UIImage is tapped with tag: 1
2014-04-18 21:47:32.680 CaseStudy[22400:60b] UIImage is tapped with tag: 2
2014-04-18 21:47:33.716 CaseStudy[22400:60b] UIImage is tapped with tag: 3
2014-04-18 21:47:34.596 CaseStudy[22400:60b] UIImage is tapped with tag: 4
```

So I guess you did something wrong.